# liquibase tempfile not deleted

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

we use liquibase with spring-boot
liquibase seems to use a big tempfile "liquibase-unzip" who take a lot of place
Each time it start, it create a new one and don't delete the old-one.

It's take a lot of space in the disk, what should I do to avoid-it ?

I'm working in an old school vm, not a docker instance

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: I use the default conf, and it seems to be a recuring issue, but none of the post I've read explain how to address it